# Android Room FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)

Tags: android, sql, orm, android-room, android-orm

I'm tying to create a database in Android Room with two foreign keys. Every time I try to insert a track into the database the program chrashes and says that the "foreign key costraint failed(code 787)". Maybe someone of you knows why and can help me.

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(
    entity = Kategorie.class,
    childColumns = "kategorieFremdschluessel",
    parentColumns = "kategorieID",
    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ),
    @ForeignKey(
            entity = Playlist.class,
            childColumns = "playlistFremdschluessel",
            parentColumns = "uuid",
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )
 })

public class Track {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int uid;

private String trackTitel;
private String playlistName;
private String jsonObjectString;
private int kategorieFremdschluessel;
private int playlistFremdschluessel;

@Ignore
public Track(String trackTitel, String playlistName, String jsonObjectString) {
    this.trackTitel = trackTitel;
    this.playlistName = playlistName;
    this.jsonObjectString = jsonObjectString;
}

public Track(String trackTitel, String jsonObjectString) {
    this.trackTitel = trackTitel;
    this.jsonObjectString = jsonObjectString;
}
//Getter and Setter

@Dao
```

TrackDao

```
public interface TrackDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Track WHERE playlistName LIKE :playlist")
List<Track> getAllTracks(String playlist);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Track WHERE kategorieFremdschluessel = :kategorieFremdschluessel")
List<Track> loadAllKategorieTracks(int kategorieFremdschluessel);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Track WHERE playlistFremdschluessel = :playlistFremdschluessel")
List<Track> loadAllPlaylistTracks(int playlistFremdschluessel);

@Insert
void insertAll(List<Track> trackList);

@Insert
void insertOne(Track track);

@Update
void updateOne(Track track);

@Delete
void delete(Track track);
}
```

"Kategorie" and "Playlist" are also tables in the database.

```
@Entity
public class Playlist{


@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int uuid;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String name;
```

Kategorie

```
@Entity
public class Kategorie {



@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int kategorieID;


@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String name;
```

Comment: Do you have rows in Kategorie and Playlist tables with uid that is same as uid of track that you are inserting?

Comment: @ElectroWeak Yes, both classes have a PrimaryKey. Kategorie = "kategorieID" and Playlist = "uuid" . So the names are identical.

Comment: No, I mean that you need to have a row in table Kategorie and Playlist with the same primary key, which is also same as the primary key of Track you are inserting.

Comment: In other words, you can't insert Track into a database if there isn't a corresponding row in Kategorie and Playlist with the same foreign key. More info about foreign keys [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: Oh okay...wow that was the problem. I'm feeling stupid because I tested everything... Okay another question then, is there a possiblity to say, that the foreign key can be null first? And when I want I can set it to the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, if you set Track's foreign key as null, you can add Track and then update it with ID, but you'd need to change `kategorieFremdschluessel` from type `int` to `Integer` because otherwise, Room generates column as NOT NULL which forbids null values in a table.

Comment: Wonderful! You are the best! I would give you a like if  I could :D Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I can post it as an answer :).

Comment: Do it! Someone will benefit from it because i searched for that answer a long time and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have rows in tables `Kategorie` and `Playlist` with a same [foreign key](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) as has `Track` that you are inserting.

Comment: @jlopez If you are getting the same error then check if there are rows in the table in which you want to insert the row. There must be a row with the same foreign key as the one in the row you want to insert.

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840478/sqliteconstraintexception-foreign-key-constraint-failed-code-787

Answer (score 4):

There's another reason why this error occurs which consumed a lot of my time since every possible solution available on the internet seemed futile in my case.

**If you use *rowId* of the parent table as the *parentColumn key*, the Foreign key constraint CANNOT be used.**

As per the [SQLite documentation on Foreign Keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> The parent key is the column or set of columns in the parent table
>   that the foreign key constraint refers to. This is normally, but not
>   always, the primary key of the parent table. The parent key must be a
>   named column or columns in the parent table, **not the rowid.**

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840478/sqliteconstraintexception-foreign-key-constraint-failed-code-787